# WebView show message "sorry has err"

Tags: android, webview

I use `WebView` for play  a video from Aparat, that is an online video service like youtube . Although it works well but in higher android version like 10 shows message `sorry has err`. I want does not show this message.

This is my code:

```
void webview() {

    WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
    ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    ws.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.reload();

    webView.loadData(Url, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass(progressBar);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
}

public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {
    ProgressBar ProgressBar = null;

    WebClientClass(android.widget.ProgressBar progressBar) {
        ProgressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

the example of Url :

```
<div id="19697445500"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/PBZfF?data[rnddiv]=19697445500&  data[responsive]=yes"></script></div>
```